# update/change animation in Android after loading from xml resource

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-resources

How can i update attribute of animation in java code after loading from xml?

I have a rain drop fall animation defined in xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromYDelta="10%p" 
    android:toYDelta="70%p"
    android:duration="2000" 
    android:repeatCount="1"
    />
   <scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.2"
    android:toXScale=".5"
    android:fromYScale="1.2"
    android:toYScale="0.5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

after loading this animation

```
 rainDropAnimation =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.cloud_fall_down);
```

how can i change `fromYDelta` of animation?
basically  i have some cloud moving on screen. i wants to show rain if user tap on a cloud. and i don't want to have to many animation resource for different rain drop image,a single animation will serve all drop juts need to change starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this could be helpful for anyone BUT I solve my problem using `TranslateAnimation`.

Here is source code of animation:
 https://github.com/naveed-ahmad/Android-Game-Pack/blob/feature/UI/src/com/nav/gamepack/shared/WelcomeActivity.java#L192

Comment: so can you not update the animation? I've a similar problem: same animation, one that go up and same that go down. Do I have to create two different animation?